# Repository pattern Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am starting to learn about Laravel 5 repository pattern, and I can't get anything right! I probably used wrong namespace or 'use'; This is the error i am getting: `Class App\Http\Controllers\ServiceController does not exist`

This is my Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace Repo;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Repo\ServiceRepository;

class ServiceController extends Controller {


    public function __construct(ServiceRepository $service){
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function showServices()
    {
        $services = $this->service->getAllServices();
        return view('services', compact('services'));
    }

}
```

Here's the repository:

```
class ServiceRepository {

    public function getAllServices(){
        return \App\Service::all();
    }
}
```

And here's my route:

```
Route::get('/services', 'ServiceController@showServices');
```

I've tried to change some namespaces but i end up with more errors :/

Comment: Please show the complete code of your controller (including namespace). Does it actually have a namespace? :)

Comment: I've updated my question @ArmenMarkossyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read a bit about namespaces in PHP.

If your `ServiceController` is located in `app/Http/Controllers` directory, then the code has to be like follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Repo\ServiceRepository;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(ServiceRepository $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function showServices()
    {
        $services = $this->service->getAllServices();

        return view('services', compact('services'));
    }
}
```

Note that I removed `namespace Repo` and the first `use` statement.

A class has to have only a single namespace, so I removed the second `Repo` namespace.

Namespaces are really simple. In most cases namespace of a class just reflects a *path* to that class. In your case, it's `App\Http\Controllers` because your controller is probably located in `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

I've removed `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller` because your `ServiceController` and `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` are in the same directory, so they are in the same namespace. When two classes are in the same namespace, a full path with a namespace is not necessary for them to be able to access each other.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help but in my controller don't I have to use 2 paths? one for the controller and the 2nd for the repository? Because when I try your answer I am getting the following error: class Repo\ServiceRepository does not exist. And by the way thanks for the explanation. PS: my repo folder (that contains the ServiceRepository file) is in folder outside app

Comment: You're welcome. My code is correct. The problem is in the fact that your ServiceRepository is also missing a proper namespace. Try to fix it yourself, so you learn how to use namespaces correctly. If you fail, write a comment here and I'll help you.

Comment: Well what's my serviceRepository class needs access to ? I undersand that namespaces are used to define a path to access another class (like controller) is that right? I've tried : namespace App\Repo;

Comment: I've fixed it by putting my repo folder in the app directory and I used the namespace App\Repo in serviceRepository. Thank youu

Comment: You're welcome! I think now you have a better understanding of namespaces :)